# Getting Error in Web Services

Tags: iphone

I am getting following response of while using web services

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode 
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher"
>a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Object reference not set to 
an instance of an object.</faultstring><detail><ExceptionDetail 
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException 
i:nil="true"/><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
<StackTrace>   at BAL.getDUCID(String DUC, String Plateform) in 
f:\DotnetSite\Websites\APSWServices\App_Code\BAL.cs:line 28&#xD;
```

at `IPhone.getHeaderAds(String Duc, String PId, String W, String H, String AdsId, String SessionId, String IMEI, String User_Agent)` in `f:\DotnetSite\Websites\APSWServices\App_Code\IPhone.cs:line 67&#xD;`

Comment: Are you sure this webservice is working according to requirement ? Please test the webservice first. If webservice is working than check you are passing correct parameters if any required.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's an web-service problem.

First you can check the web-service by passing the static values and check it's response. If it works correctly, then check with your code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

abishek dont worry it seems web service end mistake.i faced same problem couple of days back once recheck webservice with sending small file or data.